# Can you channel more air into a nozzle by creating a vortex inside of it?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, airflow, wind-power

There are designs for ducting in wind turbines to channel a wider cross section of wind into the rotor area. This is unpractical for structural and economical reasons but does actually increase power output. I was thinking if it would be possible to gather even more air from a nozzle the same size by creating a vortex inside this nozzle. Imagine imparting a spin on the entering air by rifling similar to a gun barrel. Would this vortex extend outwards of the nozzle and thus effectively increase the inlet area (A0 in the sketch)? Could the obtainable mass flow be increased? See the attached draft for a better illustration.[image]

I tried to find some publications and similar ideas to this concept. I only found this relating sounding publication (https://www.jstor.org/stable/43749083?seq=1). But as I can't access it, I can't tell if it even goes into the right direction. Do you happen to know any similar ideas?

Comment: “Ducting” of airflow into wind turbines is acheivable and is done - often by using the shape of the terrain - a tapering valley is an obvious example and since nature did the work cheap..

Comment: Mass wouldn't increase but air pressure at the fan would. You would effectively be using an evase in reverse. An [evase](https://www.aireng.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Diffuser-Outlet-Perf.pdf) is usually attached to the outlet of an exhaust fan. In this application the static pressure is reduced, which increases the efficiency of the fan.

Comment: Isn't an evase just a regular diffusor? I never heard the term before. I am specifically looking for the effect a vortex causing nozzle (or diffusor) would have, because I can't find any publications on this idea.